# How to JSON-serialize a dictionary that contains a Django PointField?

Tags: json, django, gis, postgis, geodjango

In my Django application, I have a python dictionary that looks like this:

```
myDict = {"A": 1, "B": "Z", "C": {"D":"E"},}
```

When I want to serialize this and return this dict via a curl hittable endpoint, I do the following. It works:

```
return HttpResponse(
    json.dumps(myDict), 
    content_type="application/json",
)
```

However, if I now add a value to myDict that is a PointField, like this:

```
myDict["myPoint"] = Point(70.0, 30.0,)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: <Point object at 0x111bbed90> is not JSON serializable
```

So how do I serialize a dictionary that contains a PointField? I tried the following, but it definitely doesn't work:

```
return HttpResponse(
    GeoJSONSerializer().serialize(myDict, use_natural_keys=True), 
    content_type="application/json",
)
```

Searching the internet doesn't show me any clear examples of how to serialize a dictionary that contains a PointField.